# How do I adjust the values in an array using the value change caused by a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use the drop-down list to control the order in which I view posts.

Pages can be sorted by newest or most likes.

To do that, we need to adjust the array value according to the value passed from the drop-down list, but that doesn't work.

This is the dropdown list code. The name is `dropDonwList.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select id="dropDowmListID">
            <option value="1" selected>in latest order</option>
            <option value="2">in order of likes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

I connected. the code below. The name is `firestore.dao.js`

```
async selectPosts ({...} = {}, ...) {
        let goodOrderByDir = 'desc'
        let dateOrderByDir = 'desc'

        const db = getFirestore()
        const constraints = [
            orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir), orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir),
            where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
            where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
            where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]

        var hw = document.getElementById('dropDowmListID')
        hw.addEventListener('change', function() {
            console.log('change~!!~!~!!~!!!' + hw.value)
            if (hw.value == 1) {
                constraints = [
                    orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir), orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir),
                    where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
                    where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
                    where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]
                queryRef = query(collection(db, 'posts'), ...constraints)
            }
            if (hw.value == 2) {
                constraints = [
                    orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir), orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir),
                    where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
                    where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
                    where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]
                queryRef = query(collection(db, 'posts'), ...constraints)
            }
        })

        const queryRef = query(collection(db, 'posts'), ...constraints)

        return Promise.all((await getDocs(queryRef)).docs.map(async item => {
            this._lastSelectPostsDoc = item
            const data = item.data()
            return {
                ...data
            }
        }))
    }
```

With this code I can control the order of posts.

```
const constraints = [ //latest net
            orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir), orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir),
            where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
            where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
            where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]

const constraints = [ //order of likes
            orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir), orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir),
            where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
            where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
            where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]
```

And probably, this code definitely puts the order of the posts according to the sorted array values.

```
const queryRef = query(collection(db, 'posts'), ...constraints)
```

I need to be able to reorder an array based on a condition. So I used the following method:

```
var hw = document.getElementById('dropDowmListID')
        hw.addEventListener('change', function() {
            console.log('change~!!~!~!!~!!!' + hw.value)
            if (hw.value == 1) { //When the drop-down list points to Newest
                constraints = [
                    orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir), orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir),
                    where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
                    where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
                    where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]
                queryRef = query(collection(db, 'posts'), ...constraints)
            }
            if (hw.value == 2) { //When the drop-down list is pointing to the most likes
                constraints = [
                    orderBy('good', goodOrderByDir), orderBy('date', dateOrderByDir),
                    where('visibility', '==', 'public'),
                    where('country', '==', country), where('city', '==', city),
                    where('state', '==', state), where('street', '==', street)]
                queryRef = query(collection(db, 'posts'), ...constraints)
            }
        })
```

But it didn't go as well as I thought, and I saw the following sentence:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "constraints" is read-only
```

Why is this happening? How can I put the changed array in?

Comment: You need to provide a MRE for us to look at, rather than just dumping the code from your project. There's way too much code here to parse through. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I corrected it. Is this correct?

Comment: the error you are having is because you are trying to change the value of a `const` which is read-only, if you want to change a value after its initialization you should use `let` instead.